# New Outlook Design (2023) - ComObjActive("Outlook.Application") not working anymore

Tags: autohotkey

I switched to the new outlook design.

Now this line in my Autohokey script gives an error instead of returning the Outlook object. If I switch back to the old design it works again:

```
olk := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
```

Microsoft lists the [OLE programmatic identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/ole-programmatic-identifiers-office) and it still says `Outlook.Application`

- Is there a way to find out the identifier to use for a program?
- How can I get the Outlook object with the new design?

Comment: As far as i know, it's not supported in the new version.
There is also nothing you can find about this in the documentation

Comment: This might change once the new version is officially released, hopefully.